# Copying a "vector of vector" into" array of array"

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

First I had an int array called `Myarray[51][4]` filled by data.

For sorting it  based on the second column of `Myarray`, I used the following code (using the conversion of array into a vector of vector: `my_vector[51][4]`) :

```
int Myarray [51][4];
vector< vector<int> > my_vector ;
for( const auto& row : Myarray ) 
    my_vector.push_back( vector<int>( begin(row), end(row) ) ) ;

sort( begin(my_vector), end(my_vector),
       []( const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b ) { return a[1] < b[1] ; } ) ;
```

This code has sorted  `my_vector`. Now I want to copy the sorted vector into `Myarray` again for using it as array of integer with dimension of [51][4]. How  do I do it?

Comment: Just a quick question: Are you certain that you want to compare the second elements rather than the first ones?

Comment: Why don't you just sort the arrays directly?

Comment: `int Myarray [51][4];
sort( begin(Myarray), end(Myarray),
       []( int(&a)[4], int(&b)[4] ) { return a[1] < b[1] ; } ) ;`

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes did you try compiling that? It doesn't for me with g++ (4.7  and 4.8)

Comment: @stefan oh. Arrays are not assignable. Sigh.

Comment: Re: Just a quick question; I want to sort the Myarray based on the second column and want to maintain other member of each row with the second member of row. I mean after sorting i want to to change the position of three other member in each row with the second member.

Comment: your sorting code based on that array do not work please write it for the following array:int Myarray[3][4] = {
  {3, 8, 7, 2},
  {9, 12, 0, 4},
  {12, 2, 14, 1}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest and the most obvious one:

```
for (size_t row = 0; row < my_vector.size(); ++row) {
  for (size_t col = 0; col < my_vector[row].size(); ++col) {
    Myarray[row][col] = my_vector[row][col];
  }
}
```

Or another solution without the inner loop:

```
for (size_t row = 0; row < my_vector.size(); ++row) {
  copy(my_vector[row].begin(), my_vector[row].end(), Myarray[row]);
}
```

But better stop using C-style arrays in C++ and switch to `std::vector` or `std::array` completely!

For your request in the comment here is an example with `std::vector`:

```
vector<vector<int>> my_vector =  {{3, 8, 7, 2}, {9, 12, 0, 4}, {12, 2, 14, 1}};
sort(begin(my_vector), end(my_vector),
     [](const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b) { return a[1] < b[1]; }
) ;
```

Comment: if I want to sort the following array what is the code?int Myarray[3][4] = {
  {3, 8, 7, 2},
  {9, 12, 0, 4},  
  {12, 2, 14, 1}. I want to have:                                  {12, 2, 14, 1} , {3, 8, 7, 2} , {9, 12, 0, 4}.

Comment: @MehdiTanhatalab, it is harder than I initially thought as you cannot copy array. You would have to write you own sort function. But better just stick with `std` containers, e.g. `std::vector`. Why do you prefer C-style arrays?

Comment: I have been programming using Visal Foxpro till now and a beginner in C++. There, there are only arrays but not vectors. That is why i know arrays better. bur if you recommend working with data using vector, as it may be more speed in the run time, I will shift to it.

Comment: @MehdiTanhatalab, in run-time the speed difference is almost negligible. And yes - I do recommend using `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of C-style arrays - in C++ you should want C-style arrays very-very rarely.

Comment: Thank you. I do not know what do you mean C-style array is there a C++-style array? Do you mean that why I omitted the "std::" ? I used the "using namespace std" which i did not bring here.

Comment: C++ arrays are `std::vector`, `std::array` and others. C-style arrays look like `int arrayName[arraySize]`

Comment: Would you please help me to write me the code needed for sorting following array; int Myarray[3][4] = { {3, 8, 7, 2}, {9, 12, 0, 4}, {12, 2, 14, 1}. I want to have: {12, 2, 14, 1} , {3, 8, 7, 2} , {9, 12, 0, 4}.